# Как переместить последний элемент массива - объект на первое место?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такой массив объектов
(это то что выдаёт консоль)

```
shapeToolsTarget: Array(4)
0: {id: 20, name: "Background", type: "shape"}
1: {id: 21, name: "BorderColor", type: "shape"}
2: {id: 22, name: "BorderWeight", type: "shape"}
3: {id: 3, name: "Paste", type: "text"}
```

Как мне переставить последний элемент на самое первое место(с 0 индексом)
Тоесть чтобы элемент с id: 3 был на 1 месте
shapeToolsTarget: Array(4)

```
0: {id: 3, name: "Paste", type: "text"}
1: {id: 20, name: "Background", type: "shape"}
2: {id: 21, name: "BorderColor", type: "shape"}
3: {id: 22, name: "BorderWeight", type: "shape"}
```

Comment: Вопрос - а зачем это нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что могло пойти не так?

Вы это сделали два раза.

```js
var arr = [
 {id: 20, name: "Background", type: "shape"},
 {id: 21, name: "BorderColor", type: "shape"},
 {id: 22, name: "BorderWeight", type: "shape"},
 {id: 3, name: "Paste", type: "text"}
];

arr.unshift(arr.pop());

console.log("[");
arr.forEach(item => console.log("", JSON.stringify(item)));
console.log("]");
```

Comment: Зачем такой странный вывод в консоль?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Мне показалось, что так будет легче сравнить с исходным массивом.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения :)