# Как заставить строку видеть html тэги?

Tags: javascript, html

Пользователь вводит своё, кастомное название товара в виде строки. Как можно позволить пользователю использовать в строке html теги? Например

```
'My <strong>name</strong>'.
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? -  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086782/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function valueToHTML() {
  document.getElementById('destination').innerHTML = 
    document.getElementById('source').value;
}
```

```html
<input id="source" value="My <strong>name</strong>."/>
<br/>
<button onclick="valueToHTML()">Value to HTML</button>
<div id="destination"></div>
```